# Count similar array value

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I'm trying to learn Go (or Golang) and can't seem to get it right. I have 2 texts files, each containing a list of words. I'm trying to count the amount of words that are present in both files.

Here is my code so far :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "bufio"
)

func stringInSlice(str string, list []string) bool {
    for _, v := range list {
        if v == str {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func main() {
    // Texts URL
    var list = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/alexcesaro/c9c47c638252e21bd82c/raw/bd031237a56ae6691145b4df5617c385dffe930d/list.txt"
    var url1 = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/alexcesaro/4ebfa5a9548d053dddb2/raw/abb8525774b63f342e5173d1af89e47a7a39cd2d/file1.txt"

    //Create storing arrays
    var buffer [2000]string
    var bufferUrl1 [40000]string

    // Set a sibling counter
    var sibling = 0

    // Read and store text files
    wordList, err := http.Get(list)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error while getting the url : %v", err)
    }
    defer wordList.Body.Close()

    wordUrl1, err := http.Get(url1)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error while getting the url : %v", err)
    }
    defer wordUrl1.Body.Close()

    streamList := bufio.NewScanner(wordList.Body)
    streamUrl1 := bufio.NewScanner(wordUrl1.Body)

    streamList.Split(bufio.ScanLines)
    streamUrl1.Split(bufio.ScanLines)

    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;

    //Fill arrays with each lines
    for streamList.Scan() {
        buffer[i] = streamList.Text()
        i++
    }
    for streamUrl1.Scan() {
        bufferUrl1[j] = streamUrl1.Text()
        j++
    }

    //ERROR OCCURRING HERE :
    // This code if i'm not wrong is supposed to compare through all the range of bufferUrl1 -> bufferUrl1 values with buffer values, then increment sibling and output FIND
    for v := range bufferUrl1{
        if stringInSlice(bufferUrl1, buffer) {
            sibling++
            fmt.Println("FIND")
        }
    }

    // As a testing purpose thoses lines properly paste both array
    // fmt.Println(buffer)
    // fmt.Println(bufferUrl1)

}
```

But right now, my build doesn't even succeed. I'm only greeted with this message:

```
.\hello.go:69: cannot use bufferUrl1 (type [40000]string) as type string in argument to stringInSlice
.\hello.go:69: cannot use buffer (type [2000]string) as type []string in argument to stringInSlice
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. bufferUrl1 is an array: `[4000]string`. You meant to use `v` (each
   string in `bufferUrl1`). But in fact, you meant to use the second
   variable—the first variable is the index which is ignored in the code
   below using `_`.
2. type `[2000]string` is different from `[]string`. In Go, arrays and slices are not the same. Read [Go Slices: usage and internals](http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals). I've changed both variable declarations to use slices with the same initial length using make.

These are changes you need to make to compile.

Declarations:

```
// Create storing slices
buffer := make([]string, 2000)
bufferUrl1 := make([]string, 40000)
```

and the loop on Line 69:

```
for _, s := range bufferUrl1 {
    if stringInSlice(s, buffer) {
        sibling++
        fmt.Println("FIND")
    }
}
```

As a side-note, consider using a map instead of a slice for `buffer` for more efficient lookup instead of looping through the list in `stringInSlice`.

https://play.golang.org/p/UcaSVwYcIw has the fix for the comments below (you won't be able to make HTTP requests from the Playground).

Comment: This fixed the compiling error, but now the sibling result is really weird, I've got a total of 20268 similar words on a file that's only 20000 words long compared to a 1000 words long file O.O

Comment: Since the slice is initialized to a length of 2000 and 40000, the range loop iterates over them all. Ignore empty strings, or make both slices with a length of 0 and append to them.